# backup files with many duplicated files

Tags: backup, compression

I frequently need to do a backup of a group of files, with many subfolders which contain several large, identical files.

Is there a compression scheme (.zip, .7z, etc) which can automatically detect this and not store identical files more than once?

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm on Windows (7) but the files are on a network, so I could run the compression app on any OS.

Comment: you can google for `incremental backup`.

Comment: incremental backup doesn't seem to help, as new files (many identical to existing files) are created in new folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible: https://superuser.com/questions/479074/why-doesnt-gzip-compression-eliminate-duplicate-chunks-of-data

Here's an example I came up with:

```
[jay test]$ tree .
.
`-- compressme
    |-- a
    |   `-- largefile (10MB)
    `-- b
        `-- largefile (10MB, identical to ../a/largefile)

3 directories, 2 files
[jay test]$ du -sh compressme/
21M compressme/
[jay test]$ tar -cf compressme.tar compressme/
[jay test]$ du -sh compressme.tar 
21M compressme.tar
[jay test]$ lzma -9 compressme.tar
[jay test]$ du -sh compressme.tar.lzma 
11M compressme.tar.lzma
```

Answer (score 6):

I also just went through this too.

If you compress your files into a Tar Ball, 7z's LZMA compression may or may not recognise the duplicates if they are separated too far in the Tar Ball (it's a function of Dictionary Size and a few other things).

7z has a WIM format which collects duplicates, then you can use normal LZMA compression for there. Windows Command Line Example:

```
7z a -twim "Example.wim" *
7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=on -mhc=on "Example.7z" "Example.wim"
del "Example.wim"
```

It works well, give it a go.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest 3 options that I've tried (in Windows):

1. **7zip LZMA2 compression with dictionary size of 1536Mb**
2. WinRar "solid" file
3. 7zip WIM file

I had 10 folders with different versions of a web site (with files such as *.php*, *.html*, *.js*, *.css*, *.jpeg*, *.sql*, etc.) with a total size of 1Gb (**100Mb average per folder**). While standard 7zip or WinRar compression gave me a file of about 400/500Mb, these options gave me a file of (1) **80Mb**, (2) 100Mb & (3) 170Mb respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FastPack for this: https://github.com/QuanosSolutions/FastPack